# Is it possible to load a local css file to the browser for certain domains?

Tags: css, browser, stylesheet, developer-tools

Using developer tools, I can amend a css file for a site I'm currently viewing in a browser.

I want to, effectively, do the same - but instead of amending the css file, loading a local css file, just for that particular domain.

Another way of phrasing it: "When any page of stackoverflow.com is loaded, load C:\test.css to the browser".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Have a look at http://userstyles.org.

Answer (score 0):

Userstyles.org offers CSS files for usage with the extension "Stylish", and Stylish recently announced that they are becoming evil (https://forum.userstyles.org/discussion/comment/109966/#Comment_109966) and can therefore not be used anymore.

One can use the styles with greasemonkey, but then the activation for various websites doesn't work anymore (the CSS is converted into a JS file and the list of sites where it should be applied onto is hardcoded inside an if-statement in that script). I.e. in order to use e.g. "dokuwiki highlight and full width" on a site using dokuwiki but not being http://dokuwiki.org, you have to edit that if-statement and reload.